# Firebase Hosted flutter app shows not a secure connection error when launching an external URL

Tags: firebase, flutter, ssl, ssl-certificate, firebase-hosting

When I open my Website hosted by Firebase Hosting Google Chrome or my Antivirus program does not let me access the page but shows me an error message:

This is not a secure connection.
Hackers might try to steal your data from (website), for example, passwords, messages or credit card details.
`Error code: NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID`

Any Ideas?

Comment: It's SSL certificate related, adding your index file or providing the website address will be useful.

Comment: I have checked it on Safari, Chrome, Firefox, and Brave works perfectly no cert issues.

Comment: Oh yeah, you are right, thank you. But I found another Problem :(  . If I use it with Flutter Plugin url_launcher and launch my website with launchUrl() I got the described problem.

Comment: Overall the issue is not related to flutter, it is related to SSL configuration, what is the URL of the website you are trying to launch?

Comment: It's the same link as above. When you copy-paste nothing happens. But when you launch website in flutter-app with url_launcher package then this problem occures. On all links that are with my website address

Comment: @Hooshyar where do I have to look for the index file? I still got no solution for the problem, because like this I can't use my Firebase hosted website like I want.

Comment: I’ll check and let you know

Comment: I solved it! I just had to miss out the **www.** in the url_launcher. But thank you very much @Hooshyar

Comment: nice to hear that, please. answer your question here for others to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it! I just had to exclude the `www.` in the url_launcher String and it will not display any SSL-Error.